# How to share modules across multiple AWS Lambda and Elastic Beanstalk applications?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

In several Lambda functions and Elastic Beanstalk instances for a project, they all use the same helper functions and constants.

I am trying to follow the DRY method and not hard code these parameters into each Lambda/EB application, but instead have the modules that contain them just import into each Lambda/EB application.

I was ideally hoping to

- put all these modules in a separate GitHub repo
- create a codepipeline to an S3 bucket
- import them into EB/Lambdas wherever needed

I have the first 2 steps done, but can't figure out how to import the modules from S3.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: If you are using .NET, you can publish private NuGet packages, and reuse them across apps. If not using .NET try something similar to NuGet in respective language.

Comment: I considered trying to make this a package to download with pip, but I don't think there is a streamlined way to make changes to it (like pushing to a repo and then using a code pipeline)

Comment: In addition to package deployment consider in the previous comment, can EFS be used to import the module from a mount EFS volume?

Comment: A solution to your requirement can be easily achieved by Layers in AWS Lambda.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to track changes in code is using a repo but if you need to use an s3 as a repo you can consider enabling versioning in the s3 bucket/repo and define some s3 event source to trigger your pipeline.

For using those dependencies I think it's best to consider using layer for lambda functions or shared EFS volumes in instances for Beanstalk if these dependencies are very important in size.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways I would consider:

1. turning the common code into a Pypi package. This probably requires the most effort but will result in a very simple sharing (just add it to the `requirements.txt` of both services).
2. Do mostly the same, but leave it on a GitHub repo (no need to publish the package to Pypi), then add `git+https://github.com/path/to/package-two@41b95ec#egg=package-two` to the `requirements.txt`.
3. If you are using the serverless framework - you can use [serverless-package-external](https://github.com/epsagon/serverless-package-external) plugin to copy the common code from the EB to Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Python package manager, pip, to install packages from an S3 bucket. To do so, you need to add the following to your requirements.txt file:

--extra-index-url [https://s3.amazonaws.com/[bucket_name]/[package_name]](https://s3.amazonaws.com/%5Bbucket_name%5D/%5Bpackage_name%5D)

You can then run the pip install command to install the package from the S3 bucket. Once the package is installed, you can import it into your Lambda/EB application.

Answer (score 0):

For sharing across lambdas you can use lambda layers.

[Official doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html)